# Problem with selectors in Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I have a problem with some selectors to click in my automatic test in Selenium. My test doesn't see any of the selectors that I used. There is my div which I working with:

```html
<select name="people" id="demo-htmlselect" onchange="selectConfigOption(this.value)" >
         <option value="">Choose a selection...</option>
         <option value="429" data-imagesrc="https://logicvapes-us-dev.jtiweb.co.uk/media/catalog/swatches/4/45x45/media/tobacco.png"
                                            data-description=""> Tobacco &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 27 mg/ml &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                     </option>
         <option value="432" data-imagesrc="https://logicvapes-us-dev.jtiweb.co.uk/media/catalog/swatches/4/45x45/media/menthol.png"
                                            data-description=""> Menthol &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 27 mg/ml &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                     </option>
         <option value="435" data-imagesrc="https://logicvapes-us-dev.jtiweb.co.uk/media/catalog/swatches/4/45x45/media/cherry.png"
                                            data-description=""> Cherry &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 27 mg/ml &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                     </option>
</select>
```

And my ideas (which aren't working):

```html
wd = new FirefoxDriver();

WebElement span = wd.executeScript("return document.getElementById('dd-select');");

wd.findElement(span).click();

//wd.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dd-select']/span[@class='class='dd-pointer.dd-pointer-down'']")).click();

//wd.findElement(By.xpath("value=//*[@id='432']"));

//WebElement register = wd.findElement(By.name('people'));

//wd.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Choose a selection...")).click();

//wd.findElementById("select=//*[@id='429']").click();
```

Thanks for every advice!

Comment: You want to select some value from drop down ? If your answer is yes, then which element you want to select ?

Comment: My answer is yes :) I want to select all of them - I have to check one by one whether they work correctly and add to the basket when we have them in stock

Comment: No, you can't select all of them in one shot. Like the way you do manually, can be automated in selenium.

Comment: Sorry, I mean one by one of course

Answer (score 0):

As per the html you have shared the the element is a `<select>` tag so you have to use the `Select` class an additionally induce *WebDriverWait* to choose an option and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='demo-htmlselect' and @name='people']")));
Select mySelect = new Select(elem);
//selecting the second item by value 429
mySelect.selectByValue("429");
```

Comment: I used your solution I have an error with locate of selectors:

09-18-2018 11:28:29 AM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/New Test Case FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //select[@id='demo-htmlselect' and @name='people']

Comment: @Weirdo_Mrln Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Same problem as last time:

Test Cases/New Test Case FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //select[@id='demo-htmlselect' and @name='people'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: @Weirdo_Mrln Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I used your method, and still I have problem.
(caused by: (Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //select[@id='demo-htmlselect' and @name='people']

Comment: I trying to use this method with other selectors (by text, by value) and I don't have idea what is wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to select an option from a select box.

See [Select](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

You have to use something like this:

```
WebElement element = <WEB DRIVER INSTANCE>.findElement(By.xpath(SELECTOR FOR THE SELECT ELEMENT));
Select select = new Select(element);
select.selectByValue(<VALUE OF THE SELECTED ITEM>);
```

Comment: You cannot simply pass XPath as string to `Select()` - you have to pass WebElement instead

Comment: Yes. My fault. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This drop down is made using select and option tags, so you can use select class from selenium.

```
Select drop_down = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("demo-htmlselect")));
drop_down.selectByVisibleText("Menthol");
```

Or

```
drop_down.selectByValue("432");
```

Comment: I had to change driver(). method to variable, because there was an error. 
Nevertheless, I still have an error regarding the incorrect location of the element.
And below I add some logs:

Comment: Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 62.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 97723, moz:profile: /var/folders/y2/_xzf44bx5k1..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 17.7.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}

Comment: *** Element info: {Using=id, value=demo-htmlselect}
Test Cases/New Test Case FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #demo\-htmlselect